# Select the selected data from firebase(Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I would like to select data such as "2" and "123" as it appears in the photo. this "2" and "123" as the chip id I defined as I want to select through the firebase database. So instead of taking all of the data in the chipItem, I just want to get certain data in firebase.

```
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        self.items.removeAll()

        for chipItem: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{



            let chipId: String = chipItem.key


            let titles: DataSnapshot = chipItem.childSnapshot(forPath: "titles")




            for device in titles.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

                print("Got device: ", device)

                let value: NSDictionary = device.value as! NSDictionary

                let deviceTitle: String = value["title"] as! String
                let deviceId: String = value["id"] as! String

                let deviceState: Bool = chipItem.childSnapshot(forPath: "states/\(deviceId)").value as! Bool

                let newDevice = Device()

                newDevice.title = deviceTitle
                newDevice.chipId = chipId
                newDevice.state = deviceState
                newDevice.id = deviceId

                self.items.append(newDevice)
            }

        }


        self.tableView.reloadData()




    }) { (err:Error) in

        print("got an error: ", err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [queryEqualToValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

```
ref.queryEqual(toValue: "123").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in 
    ...
}
```

Also use [observeSingleEvent() or observe()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) depending what you need

Answer (score 0):

`for chipItem: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{

let chipId: String = chipItem.key`

here I need to make changes that do not work the way you do. "snapshot.children.allObjects" instead of allObjects, I need to call the selected data.